# Listening to events with a provided callback param in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

My node.js server is connected to a websocket. It continuosly sends the `Events.emit('ws-price', data)`:

From another part of the js file, we can start and stop listening for those events. To be able to removeListener - same callback function should be used for both `Events.on` and `Events.off`.

How would I access a provided "bot" param in "run" and "stop" functions within the callback method ?

```js
const Events = require('../services/events')

module.exports = {
  run: async (bot) => {
    Events.on('ws-price', callback(event, bot)) // <--- pass "bot" variable
  },

  stop: async (bot) => {
    Events.off('ws-price', callback(event, bot)) // <--- pass "bot" variable
  }
}

const callback = (event, bot) => {
  console.log(bot?.id, event) // How to access "bot" here ?
}
```

I get an error: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a wrapper function that closes over `bot` that, when it's called, calls `callback` with both the `bot` and the `event` it receives. Then remember that function so you can remove it when `stop` is called (a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is good for that):

```
// A map of the current callbacks (have been `run` and not `stop`ped)
const callbacks = new Map();
module.exports = {
    run: async (bot) => {
        const cb = (event) => callback(event, bot);
        callbacks.set(bot, cb);
        Events.on("ws-price", cb);
    },

    stop: async (bot) => {
        const cb = callbacks.get(bot);
        if (cb) {
            callbacks.delete(bot);
            Events.off("ws-price", cb);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: *(Oops, slight editing error on the `stop` call. Hit refresh if you don't see just `Events.off("ws-price", cb);`.)*

Comment: Thank you, it works as it should. I had to replace a Map key from `bot` to `bot.id` to make it work, as `bot` is an object, I didn't mentioned that.

Comment: @aspirinemaga - It's fine to use objects as keys in a `Map`. But if they have unique IDs and you want to use those instead, that works too. :-)